# Obscure network fault, Server2012/Win8 - Code = (34) STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED, Printer GPO

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, user-permissions, roaming-profile, windows-8

Anyone got any clues what could possibly be causing this error.

Environment is Server 2012 and Windows 8 with roaming user profiles, \Server\Profile$ & \Server\User$.

The trigger that causes this is applying or deleting a printer via GPO.  Without doing that the roaming profiles work fine.

Problem is as soon as I add a printer GPO the user profile fails to logon with the error:

```
Windows cannot copy file \\?\UNC\Server\Profile$\Test.V2\AppData\ to location \\?\C:\Users\Test\AppData\.
This error may be caused by network problems or insufficient security rights. 
DETAIL - The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

At which point the user can no-longer connect to either \Server\Profile$ & \Server\User$ but other shares are unaffected.

We then run network monitor and trace the failing packet to:

```
System    x.x.x.5    WIN8     SMB2    SMB2:R  - NT Status: System - Error, 
Code = (34) STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED  IOCTL (0xb)     {NbtSS:3, TCP:2, IPv4:1}
```

No event logs on the server logging any events at this particular time.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What type of GPO (computer/user), (login/software install)?  You might consider including the GPO in this question.  Does the GPO work on a user WITHOUT a roaming profile as a test?

Comment: Computer GPO both Policy and Preferences cause the same problem.  Not sure details of the GPO matter, any printer GPO seems to cause the problem.  Further reading elsewhere is beginning to suggest this may be a bug related to SMB2.